# Regex: match underscore-wrapped words unless they start with @ / #

Tags: javascript, regex, markdown, tiptap

I'm trying to work around [this bug](https://github.com/scrumpy/tiptap/issues/632) in Tiptap (a WYSIWYG editor for Vue) by passing in a custom regex so that the regex that identifies italics notation in Markdown (`_value_`) would not be applied to strings that start with `@` or `#`, e.g. `#some_tag_value` would not get transformed into #some*tag*value.

This is my regex so far - `/(^|[^@#_\w])(?:\w?)(_([^_]+)_)/g`
Edit: new regex with help from @ Wiktor Stribiżew `/(^|[^@#_\w])(_([^_]+)_)/g`

While it satisfies most of the common cases, it currently still fails when
underscores are mid-word, e.g. ant_farm_ should be matched (ant*farm*)

I have also provided some "should match" and "should not match" cases here https://regexr.com/50ibf for easier testing

**Should match** (between underscores)

```
_italic text here_
police_woman_
_fire_fighter
a thousand _words_
_brunch_ on a Sunday
```

**Should not match**

```
@ta_g_
__value__
#some_tag_value
@some_value_here
@some_tag_
#some_val_
#_hello_
```

Comment: Looks like that is a problem related to using `\w` that also matches underscore. Try `(^|[^@#\w])(_([^_]+)_)`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9UwX4u/2).

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Unfortunately it won't match ant_farm_

Comment: Interesting. This does solve the problem with double leading underscoes! But `police_woman_` is still not matched in your link as well

Comment: That is because you have `\w` in the first group. Try `(?:^|\s)[^@#\s_]*(_([^_]+)_)`, see https://regex101.com/r/9UwX4u/3

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew `_something_,police_woman_` won't work

Comment: Does this https://regex101.com/r/N5K9yf/1/ serves your all cases ? just see the values in capture group 1

Comment: @CodeManiac unfortunately I don't have control over what capture groups are used. I can only pass in the regex to a 3rd party component

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your last regex works really well! I think we can live with the edge case that Alex brought up. Would you like to submit it as a separate answer?

Comment: So, `(?:^|\s)[^@#\s_]*(_([^_]+)_)` works as you need?

Comment: Yes, it's the closest to a fully working option, so right now I'm rolling with that, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following pattern:

```
(?:^|\s)[^@#\s_]*(_([^_]+)_)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9UwX4u/3/)

**Details**

- `(?:^|\s)` - start of string or whitespace
- `[^@#\s_]*` - 0 or more chars other than `@`, `#`, `_` and whitespace
- `(_([^_]+)_)` - Group 1: `_`, 1+ chars other than `_` (captured into Group 2) and then `_`.

Comment: For anyone stumbling upon this in the future - I've now slightly simplified it (it no longer captures some_tag_value at all, since we discovered that Slack and some other Markdown-compatible editors also don't do that) - `(?:^|\s)(_([^_]+)_)`

Answer (score 2):

For science, this monstrosity works in Chrome (and Node.js).

```js
let text = `
<strong>Should match</strong> (between underscores)

_italic text here_
police_woman_
_fire_fighter
a thousand _words_
_brunch_ on a Sunday

<strong>Should not match</strong>

@ta_g_
__value__
#some_tag_value
@some_value_here
@some_tag_
#some_val_
#_hello_
`;

let re = /(?<=(?:\s|^)(?![@#])[^_\n]*)_([^_]+)_/g;
document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = text.replace(re, '<em>$1</em>');
```

```css
div { white-space: pre; }
```

```html
<div/>
```

This captures `_something_` as full match, and `something` as 1st capture group (in order to remove the underscores). You can't capture just `something`, because then you lose the ability to tell what is inside the underscores, and what is outside (try it with `(?<=(?:\s|^)(?![@#])[^_\n]*_)([^_]+)(?=_)`).

There are two things that prevent it being universally applicable:

- Look-behinds are not supported in all JavaScript engines
- Most regexp engines do not support variable-length look-behinds

EDIT: This is a bit stronger, and should allow you to additionally `match_this_and_that_ but not @match_this_and_that` correctly:

```
/(?<=(?:\s|^)(?![@#])(?!__)\S*)_([^_]+)_/
```

Explanation:

```
_([^_]+)_    Match non-underscory bit between two underscores
(?<=...)     that is preceded by
(?:\s|^)     either a whitespace or a start of a line/string
             (i.e. a proper word boundary, since we can't use `\b`)
\S*          and then some non-space characters
(?![@#])     that don't start with `@`, `#`,
(?!__)       or `__`.
```

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/N5K9yf/3)

Comment: Yeah, if Firefox were to support negative lookbehinds, I could use that : (

Answer (score 0):

Here's something, it's not as compact as other answers, but I think it's easier to understand what is going on. Match group `\3` is what you want.

*Needs the multiline flag*

```
^([a-zA-Z\s]+|_)(([a-zA-Z\s]+)_)+?[a-zA-Z\s]*?$
```

- `^` - match the start of the line
- `([a-zA-Z\s]+|_)` - multiple words or `_`
- `(([a-zA-Z\s]+)_)+?` - multiple words followed by `_` at least once, but the minimum match.
- `[a-zA-Z\s]*?` - any final words
- `$` - the end of the line

In summary the breakdown of the things to match one of

- `_<words>_`
- `<words>_<words>_`
- `<words>_<words>_<words>`
- `_<words>_<words>`

Comment: Thanks for contributing! I should've mentioned this in the original question (it's only mentioned under the question's comments currently) that I can't dictate the match groups that get used by the 3rd party component later. I can only override the `inputRules` of [this class](https://github.com/scrumpy/tiptap/blob/master/packages/tiptap-extensions/src/marks/Italic.js#L33-L34), but [`markInputRule`](https://github.com/scrumpy/tiptap/blob/master/packages/tiptap-commands/src/commands/markInputRule.js) will have a very specific match logic.